# Is there a way to make text "not copyable" in RStudio RMarkdown?

Tags: r, copy, yaml, rstudio, r-markdown

I'm teaching a few R coding workshops in a couple of weeks. Students like to receive the materials in advance and I like to provide them with the `RMarkdown` HTML files that act as the lecture notes.

In class, I prefer students to not "`copy and paste`" code. Instead, I go through the lectures at a slower pace so that students can practice writing out the code, which I think really helps facilitate learning.

Is there a way to specify in the YAML section that the text is not "`copyable`" when I output the `.html` file?

I know I can just save the output as `.pdf` and run it through an app, but I prefer the output to not be "`paged`" and to have the interactive table of contents, if possible.

Comment: Think carefully whether this is actually a valid goal. Making text noncopyable (besides being a hack that can always be circumvented, albeit potentially with some effort) directly makes your document less useful. Why not using different incentives for the students to write the code themselves rather than copying and pasting (e.g. by giving them incomplete code, to complete for themselves)? Come to think of it, is copying and pasting actually a problem? In general, **be very wary of things that artificially restrict usability.** Good UIs empower users, they don’t take power away from them.

Comment: Thanks Konrad for your thoughts! I provide the students with the "copyable" versions after class. I don't think any of them will be motivated to get around this, either. I used to print the lectures and provide them but this would be better for the environment. It's also just an interesting question I couldn't find the answer to.

Comment: @Nova I am actually not sure this is doable directly in ``R Mardown``. Altough I suppose you could simply modify the ``html`` document produce by ``R Markdown`` to make it not copyable. I'm pretty sure this is possible in pure html or with css.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, perhaps it is useful for muscle-memory for students to be typing in code, even if it is just reading it and typing with minimal updates/corrections/insertions. While it is relevant to each student's learning style (reading, auditory, practice/experiment), I'd think there would be more benefits than detractors. I found in my classes most students copy/paste blindly without trying to understand the syntax or meaning, whereas typing it helped them to understand *just a little more*. (I agree that it can be "easily" circumvented, not always a big-enough problem.)

Comment: @r2evans Yes. I’m not fundamentally arguing against the benefits of writing code yourself over copying and pasting. I *am* arguing against deteriorating usability by creating barriers to achieve this aim. (And an aside, since it’s an important and widespread misconception: the notion of different preferred learning styles is a myth.)

Comment: Konrad, while I personally disagree with your statement that it is a misconception (and empirically I believe I've seen differences in the classroom), I certainly don't *"know with statistical confidence or certainty"*, and don't want to start a war over it. I respect your thoughts on it. You raise good points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a quick hack, based on a starting point suggested here: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/u/user-select/

```r
library(shiny)

css <- ".nocopy {
  -webkit-user-select: none;  /* Chrome all / Safari all */
  -moz-user-select: none;     /* Firefox all */
  -ms-user-select: none;      /* IE 10+ */
  user-select: none;          /* Likely future */      
}"
func <- "func <- function(x, y, ...) {
  x + y
}"

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$style(HTML(css)),
  "Copyable:",
  tags$pre(func),
  tags$hr(),
  tags$p("Not copyable:", class = "nocopy"),
  tags$pre(func, class = "nocopy")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

And as this suggests, it can apply to various HTML elements including `<p>` and `<pre>`. I have not tested on other elements.

---

As almost any web-dev will tell you, though, this is *trivial* to defeat. Using FF (most browsers have similar functionality):

- `Ctrl-I` (shortcut for *Tools > Web Developer &; Toggle Tools*)
- `Ctrl-Shift-C` (*"Pick and element from the page"*)
- click on the element you want to be able to highlight and copy
- in the code-editor in the bottom of the page, change `class="nocopy"` to `class=""` (or anything else)

The result of doing this on the `"Not copyable:"` text can be seen here:

[image: web-dev tool console showing modified css]

(I show these steps to clearly indicate that I believe this is meant to be a shallow attempt at discouraging laziness. Those who choose a more-active-laziness (??) will have no problem doing so. If they're really determined, they'll just delete the definition of `.nocopy` directly to have an effect on the whole page. But, then again, you cannot force students to learn the way you intend :-)

---

**Edit**:

This works just as easily in an Rmd file:

File: `Nova.css`

```css
.nocopy {
  -webkit-user-select: none;  /* Chrome all / Safari all */
  -moz-user-select: none;     /* Firefox all */
  -ms-user-select: none;      /* IE 10+ */
  user-select: none;          /* Likely future */
}
```

File: `Nova.Rmd`

````
---
output: html_document
css: Nova.css
---

Copyable:

```{r chunk1}
func1 <- function(x, y, ...) {
  x + y
}
```

<p class="nocopy">Not copyable:</p>

```{r chunk2, class.source = "nocopy"}
func2 <- function(x, y, ...) {
  x + y
}
```
````

There are two [`knitr` options](https://yihui.name/knitr/options/#text-results) you can use here: `class.source=` and `class.output=`. I'm assuming you'd want the source to be "protected", but you might want the output as well.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting a solution, @r2evans! I don't use `shiny` so I'm not sure how to apply this to my `.Rmd`.

Comment: Look good, that is the css I use to "block" copying text on html page. Would it work if you copy the ``".nocopy{}..."`` inside the  ``<style type="text/css">
</style>`` of a R Markdown output .html file? I didn't get it to work.

Comment: @Nova, oops, that was my assumption. However, if you are rendering HTML documents, it should work just as easily there. See my edit in a few minutes ...

Comment: Thank you so much r2evans! That works a treat! I love the `class.source = "nocopy"`, that's what I was really after and I can set it in the first code chunk with `knitr::opts_chunk$set(class.source = "nocopy", class.output = "nocopy")`. You're a star! If you think my question has merit, please consider giving it a vote. Thank you again!

Comment: Setting the default makes sense. You should be able to have a copyable (not "not") code block by manually setting `class.source=""` for a particular block, perhaps one with data you don't need them to type in. Glad it worked for you.